# Is any admin panel tool is available for mysql?

Tags: mysql

I developing one website using PHP and Mysql. For that I need admin panel tool for mysql. Is there any admin panel tool is available in market. If yes, Kindly suggest me best tool either paid or free tool.

Comment: phpmyadmin , mysql workbench , sqlyog

Comment: haven't you tried localhost/phpmyadmin if you have apache installed. mysqlworkbench is also good and SQLbuddy as well.

Comment: I think my question may be wrong. If I configure my DB, it will auto generate UI and list out values available in DB in the field. I am asking for Data entry operation. For example visit this link. http://crud-admin-generator.com/. Thanks.

Comment: You're kidding, right?

Answer (score 0):

SQLYog is the best admin tool for MySQL. I have been using this tool since last 4 years. It has powerful Schema and database synchronization tool.